# No layers in plot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table that look like below,

```
chr1    500     15      0.502   na
chr1    1000    21      0.641   0.019704955
chr1    1500    21      0.621   0.016777844
chr1    2000    22      0.534   na
chr1    2500    35      0.698   0.028712731
chr2    4500    2       0.371   na    
chr2    5000    3       0.342   na    
chr4    5500    1       0.068   na    
chr4    6000    0       0.000   na    
chr4    6500    0       0.000   na    
chr5    7000    2       0.079   na    
chr5    7500    12      0.440   na
```

From this table, I would like to generate multiple plots - one for each chr- where Xaxis and Y axis will be column 2 and 5.

Based on a response to another question, I tried this,

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
Y <- read.table("integ.pi")
names(Y) <- c("Chr","Window","SNPs","covfra","pi")
chrs <- levels(Y[,"Chr"])
c <- lapply(chrs, function(chr) {
ggplot(Y[Y[, "Chr"]==chr,], aes(x=as.factor(Window), y=pi)) 
})  
lapply(c)
```

But I am an error

> "Error: No layers in plot".

How should I go about this? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Cheers,

Comment: Well, as the message suggests: add a layer to your plot, like `geom_point` or something. See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggplot.html

Comment: you'll need to define _what_ to plot with `ggplot`. If you want points (a scatterplot), `geom_point`, if you want lines, `geom_line`. Try reading a ggplot tutorial, there are a lot if you google.

Comment: As a side comment: `c()` is a function in R. Therefore, it's bad practice to name variables `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple example to see how to use the commands:

```
library(ggplot2)

dt = data.frame(Chr = c("c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c3"),
                x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                y = c(2,4,5,2,3,4,6,6,7))

ggplot(dt, aes(x,y, col=Chr)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(. ~ Chr) # remove this to have all lines in same plot
```